# Android AdMob - Ad without XML

Tags: android, admob

Is there a simple way to add an add to the top of an app by code, without using XML layouts? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing the same as a normal `View` in Android.

From the code do an `add()` on a `ViewGroup` of the admob view.